# 22.04 Server on Dell r710 has started shutting down shortly after boot

Tags: shutdown

I'm not really well conversed in Ubuntu, I know just enough to be dangerous. I've been running a homelab/server for several years now, mostly for running docker containers, game servers, etc. I'm not sure what's happened recently, but my server is now shutting down shortly after boot, and I'm not even really sure how to start diagnosing it, so I figured I'd come here for help. I've already replaced the power supplies, so pretty sure that's not it. The system doesn't just lose power, either, I briefly see the GRUB Ubuntu 22.04 screen as it's powering down, so I think something is sending a termination signal. I'm reasonably sure it's not a hardware issue; I actually had this identical problem many years ago when 18.04 came out, and I updated to it--rolling back to 16.04 worked fine, so I suspect it may be kernel related. I've started on the prior kernel, however, and still the same issue. Can you kind folks tell me where to start on diagnosing this?

--Chris

Comment: Here you go https://superuser.com/questions/106006/linux-how-do-i-diagnose-isolate-whats-causing-random-hangs-and-spontaneous

Comment: Have you checked the bios battery ?

Comment: Thanks for the link, Mike, that looks like some good info.  I don't think my symptoms are indicative of the bios battery, Marco, but I'll check it out nonetheless.  Thank you both!

Comment: Can't be reproduced because it was a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for replies, everyone.  I ended up concluding that it was in fact a hardware issue--strange, because it passed all Lifecycle tests, but I couldn't get any live image to work properly, and eventually it stopped booting.  Replaced with an r730, which works fine.  I simply popped the drives in, rebooted, amended the interfaces file and I'm back up.  Cheers.